# Forecasting a seasonal series with R

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I am working with the program "R". I used the command "seas (X-13)" to deseasonalize my quarterly series, then I did the forecast with it. Therefore my forecast is in deseasonalized terms.

Now, I was asked to compare my forecast with the IMF (International Monetary Fund) projections... Is my forecast comparable with it?, or what can I do to make it comparable?

Comment: Assuming either an additive or a multiplicative model, once you've removed the seasonal component you're basically fitting the trend and forecasting it. So I guess that your forecast is comparable with IMF's one as long as your low-pass filter for the trend skims the way IMF does.

Answer (score 1):

There is this very good book on forecasting by [Rob Hyndman and George Athanasopoulos](https://otexts.com/fpp2/).

There you find very useful tips and R code. Have a look at the chapter on [time series decomposition](https://otexts.com/fpp2/decomposition.html) there you find relevant stuff about seasonal time series.

Comment: Many Thanks for your answer!